# New property for indexing service on Windows Server 2008 - Where to put registery entry

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-registry, indexing-service

I'm trying to set up a new property in the indexing service for Server 2008.  I've followed the tutorial here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19540/Microsoft-Indexing-Service-How-To which is all fine up until the point where you have to add an entry to the registery at this location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ContentIndexCommon for the DefaultColumnFile entry so that you can use the new property in your queries.  This registery location doesn't exist on Server 2008.

Can anyone help me with where I add this registry entry in Server 2008 please?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.massmind.org/techref/language/asp/ix/ixrgsman.htm) correlates the need for `ContextIndexCommon`.

Simply create a key called `ContentIndexCommon` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\` and add the values there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately though, even after adding the key and the required entry the "friendly name" is still not showing up in the index properties so I'm still unable to access the value in code.

Comment: @Carbonara I don't think that's your issue then. To make sure your registry key is being read, can see if its being read by anything with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Also look for read failures on similarly named registry keys.